# Is there a way to fetch the attachments of an email message?

Tags: ruby, pop3

I'm using the default `net/pop` class in order to fetch emails from a specific email account. From each message, I need to read all attachments and extract some data from them. But I can't find any way to achieve that! Seems like the `POPMail` class doesn't have a specific method to get the message's attachments.